# Notify my WCF service when my database is updated

Tags: sql, wcf, sql-server-2005, triggers, notifications

I have a WCF service that needs to notify it's clients when changes occur to the database (sql server 2005). This is relatively easy accomplished, as long as I find a way to notify my ***service*** of any changes. I can probably create a database trigger on a table and have that trigger start a small service client that notifies my service, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this? It would be a viable solution to have the service poll the database for changes, but I'm not sure on the best way to do it (and sendign a notification to my service would be preferred).

As the relevant updates apply only to a certain part of the database, I was also wondering if it's also possible to link such a trigger (or other mechanism) to a database diagram.

All help is appreciated!
rinze

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your database is SQL Server 2005 and above you can try this solution: [Remove pooling for data changes from a WCF front end](http://rusanu.com/2007/11/01/remove-pooling-for-data-changes-from-a-wcf-front-end/).

As a side note, never call external processes from a trigger, don't make web calls from a trigger. Is a guaranteed recipe for disaster.

**Update**

For those interested in mixing Query Notifications with LINQ to SQL I recommend [Using SQLDependency objects with LINQ](http://dunnry.com/blog/UsingSQLDependencyObjectsWithLINQ.aspx).

Comment: OK, this blog does (almost) exactly what I'm doing here. As I'm using LINQ to SQL, it's a bit less straightforward, but shouldn't be a problem. Do you know if it's possibly to add a dependency on a database diagram (or a view, to simulate it)?
Thanx for the link!

Comment: I haven't thought about using LINQ and SqlDependency in combination. I'll see how this can be achieved and post back.

Comment: See my update, Ryan Dunn has already blogged about SqlDependency and Linq2sql.

Answer (score 1):

Look at

- [SQL Server 2005 Query Notifications Tell .NET 2.0 Apps When Critical Data Changes](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0605061)
- [Change Notification with Sql Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877273/change-notification-with-sql-server-2008)