# How to pass a message from 2 .Net applications

Tags: .net, wcf, tcp

I have a .Net windows service running on a customers server. On the customers factory floor there a number of pc's running another .Net application. My server application is polling the db, and when certain changes have been made, I'd like to message the factory pc's to update.

The message being sent will be a simple string. What is the best way to implement this? I've been looking at WCF, but I'm not quite sure how to create a publisher/subscriber model using it.

Many thanks.

Comment: Try creating a new wcf project, you'll get a great starting point. Notice that wcf passes objects (wraps the serialization process for you, if you implement tcp/udp you'll need to serialize and deserialize your objects yourself (not so hard though). Good luck

Comment: [Any good WCF publish/subscribe framework tutorials out there?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193518/any-good-wcf-publish-subscribe-framework-tutorials-out-there)

Comment: I think the best option would be implement a notification service with subscriber. Any client can subscribe to be notified when an event is fired.
Here is a similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406534/notify-my-wcf-service-when-my-database-is-updated