# Notification services in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, service, notifications

I have a SQL Server database and several clients that use it (via a C# application). In the database I have a table and each record of this table has a field (status flag) which is changed by clients on run time. Now when a client change the status of a record in the database I want SQL Server to inform the other clients about this change immediately.

After searching, I found that Notification Services (NS) in SQL Server 2005 is suitable for this scenario, but I heard that NS is not supported in SQL Server 2008.

Now, what is the substitute of NS in SQL Server 2008 ?

Comment: [Duplex Binding in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) is one other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well [SQLDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) is still around. This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877273/change-notification-with-sql-server-2008) is discussing the options in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I used it and my problem was solved. But apparently in this method you can't notify wich change has been done, SQL only notifys a change is occured.