# How can SQLServer notify a vb.net application of an event?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, architecture, messaging

Is there a relatively simple way that my VB.NET application can be notified of the fact that a new  value has been written to a table in SQL Server Express 2008?  Polling is not an option since I'd need to do that every 10 seconds nonstop.

Comment: John, I removed my answer because I don't think you can using Query Notification with Express.  Sorry about that.  You might want to check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877273/change-notification-with-sql-server-2008); the answer by RickNZ discusses altnerate options for what you want to do though I don't know if any of them can be used in SQL Express.

Comment: Jay - It looks like this will work with Express, but for the life of me I can't find anything that will help as much as I think the links you sent yesterday will.  Will you provide those links again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at having your application subscribe to [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx).

Also [Using Query Notifications in .NET 2.0 to handle ad-hoc data refreshes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/QueryNotifications.aspx)

Comment: This looks just right - except for one thing.  Are you sure I can do this with SQL Server 2008 EXPRESS?  The second link your provided says it won't work with 2005 Express.