# How to check records continuously in vb.net 2008 if a condition is met

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Please, how can check a record continuously from sql database using vb.net 2008 if a condition is met?
Assuming connection has been established and the display of the in records has also been done. The moment the program is launched, the checking starts...
I know about threading but how to implement it. Please help. Thank u in advance.

Ben

Comment: Is this what you're looing for: "How can SQLServer notify a vb.net application of an event?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617278/how-can-sqlserver-notify-a-vb-net-application-of-an-event ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use a Timer. Sure it'll block your UI, but you can also access your UI from there.

Let's assume that you have these things:

- Sub Check() - Checks the database for changes. Calls Update(stuff) if there are changes
- Sub Update(stuff) - Updates the UI with stuff.

Create a timer. In the tick event, call Check().

Alternatively, if you really want to create multiple threads, in your form load, start a thread that loops forever:

```
Sub CheckContinuously()
    While True
         Check()
         Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End While
End Sub

Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf CheckContinously)
```

To stop this thing, you'll need to change the while condition. I would stick with the timer if the processing time is short.

Comment: If you need further help with this email me I can help you thread the things you need threaded.