# How to refresh a datagridview for new stored data?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

Hi everyone I have a **DataGridView**, inside of it is 2 columns, **FullName** and **VoteCount**. I want to refresh the DataGridView, for changes in my Database. How do I refresh the DatagridView without closing the form or clicking any button? Is it possible?

Here's my code :

```
    private void President()
    {
        sc.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT (LastName + ', ' + FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName) as FullName,Vcount as VoteCount FROM TableVote WHERE Position='President'", sc);

        try
        {
            _da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            _da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
            _da.Fill(_dt);
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = _dt;
            PresDG.DataSource = bs;
            _da.Update(_dt);

            PresDG.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            PresDG.Columns["FullName"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            PresDG.Columns["VoteCount"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            PresDG.Columns["VoteCount"].Width = (100);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could do it in another thread i guess, which would fire some method every few minutes or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to re-fill the complete DataGridView.

Ways:

1. You do it with the Microsoft Tick-Class, in a given interval
2. You use the Microsoft Tick-Class for checking changes in your database. If there are some changes, re-fill your complete DataGridView.

Comment: got the idea thanks so much haha im done with my voting system.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Call this function when ever you want to refresh your data.

```
YourGrid.DataSource = Refresh("SELECT...");

private BindingSource Refresh(string sql)
{
    try
    {
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString)) { FillLoadOption = LoadOption.Upsert })
        {
            da.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
            da.Fill(dataSet.YourTable);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

    return new BindingSource(dataSet, "YourTable");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your database get update frequently? if so you can use a periodic update using a timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sql server CLR integration.
[Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/05/03/a-quick-walk-through-of-clr-integration-with-sql-server.aspx)
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254963%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

I will be posting in more details after a little reading however i hope it can give you a direction till that or you may find your solution.

**UPDATE** 
You can create a Trigger application and use that trigger application to call your method for binding gridview . 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874699/trigger-windows-service-when-the-new-record-insert-in-to-db) is a good example to write an trigger and implementing it .

[CLR SP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37298/CLR-Stored-Procedure-and-Creating-It-Step-by-Step)

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases:

- If you refresh you datagridview frequently, you set an timer to
  update the result.
- If refresh after insert or update operation, at
  the end of the operation recall your binding method.

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer and do this

```
string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlDataAdapter adptr = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM " + tableName, conn);
DataTable tabloSql = new DataTable();
adptr.Fill(tabloSql);
dataGridView1.DataSource = tabloSql;
```

Note: Do this if your program doesn't make changes on your DataTable.
if it makes changes on datatable when you refresh the table your changes on datatable will delete