# How do I listen for SQL Server database changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Using .Net 4.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2

I have been looking into utilizing SqlDependency / SqlNotifications for monitoring some database structures. Is the best process / practice for this to utilize the SqlDependency / SqlNotifications with SQL Server Service broker?

Are folks using other methods to accomplish a similar task? I could always poll for changes, but I would rather not have to do that. On the other hand I don't want to introduce a complex scenario into our existing environment either.

**EDIT (Potential Options):**

1. SqlDependency
2. Service Broker External Activation

Comment: FYI - SQL Notification services was deprecated, so I wouldn't try to go down that path.  This sounds somewhat related (not exactly) to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877273/change-notification-with-sql-server-2008

Comment: What kind of structures?  Data?  Schema?  Also, why do you want to do this / what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @RQDQ we have a high volume application where we have to perform quite a few DB lookups.  I wanted to try and eliminate some of this overhead by caching or leveraging something else to store the static data...until changed

Comment: @ChrisLively thanks.....I will take a look at the stack question

Comment: @RQDQ...sorry also meatn to say it is for Data Changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out event notifications:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175854.aspx