# Listening to SQL Server database changes

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I want to get a notification in Android when my (SQL Server database) updated; there is any way in Android to do this?

C# provide (SQLDependency) service to do this. So, I want same this service in Android->Java.

After the search for solutions, I had seen the below links, but not useful for me.

1- [How do I listen for SQL Server database changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299620/how-do-i-listen-for-sql-server-database-changes)

2- [Getting data from SqlDependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877505/getting-data-from-sqldependency)

3- [Get notified when database change Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242438/get-notified-when-database-change-android)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why are they not useful?  What you want isn't simple, but the first link seems a good start.

Comment: Because does not provide to me any solutions for my case.
"What you want isn't simple". In C# is very simple to do it; so I think there is a simple way in java to do it.

Comment: @user8476418 C# uses the .NET framework, which is owned by Microsoft; SQL Server is also owned by Microsoft, so there is extra effort put into making them work together well. Microsoft has no incentive to do the same thing for Java, so there is probably less support for features like that for Java and SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

There is a talk [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190615/how-to-listen-for-sqlite-database-changes-in-android)

A good example is the media API, where it encapsulates the media database. an example is [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners)

If the database belongs to your application, you can trigger custom event and who wants to be notified can listen it.