# Polling database to print out files

Tags: c#

I need a program that sends any files in my database (MSSQL) to my printer. I thought of using something like this:

```
Thread.Sleep(20000);
```

So every 20 seconds I check my database if there are any changes and if so, print the files. But I was wondering if there is a better way? 
Something to send interrupts to my program when the database changed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Notification with Sql Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877273/change-notification-with-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Is the content of the files actually stored inside the database?

Comment: Yes, the content is inside the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Timer to poll the database. The timer raises the Elapsed event every N seconds in which you can query your database:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    System.Timers.Timer DatabaseTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    //set the inteval to 20 seconds. Interval is in milliseconds so 20 sec = 20000 milisec
    DatabaseTimer.Interval = 20000;
    //start the timer
    DatabaseTimer.Enabled = true;
    //set the eventhandler, which is called every 20 seconds
    DatabaseTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(DatabaseTimer_Elapsed);
}
static void DatabaseTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    //Your database query / printing here
}
```

You can read more about Timers at MSDN  here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks! Looks pretty much like what I need.