# asp.net/vb be notified of new table entires from sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a aspx page and I want to be notified via the aspx page whenever there is a new entry in a particular db table.

I only have 1 laptop which is running both sql server 2012 and visual studio express for web.

currently i am thinking of creating a 1px by 1px frame and put it inside the master page.

the frame will contain codes for sql select and I will set it to auto refresh every 5 mins.

is there a way for sql server to notify the aspx page of new entries instead of the aspx page periodically doing a sql select?

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877273/change-notification-with-sql-server-2008) for how to make SQL server notify a .NET app of changes.

If you are using HTML 5 you could make a [WebSockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) connection to your server that will notify the WebSocket when it receives a change event from SQL Server:

> The WebSocket specification defines an API establishing "socket" connections between a web browser and a server. In plain words: There is an persistent connection between the client and the server and both parties can start sending data at any time.

There is a guide [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617611/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-4-5-Part-1) for how to implement this using ASP.NET. In .NET 4.5 you essentially have 3 choices:

> - *Using HttpContext.AcceptWebSocketRequest*
> - Creating a WCF service with CallbackContract and the new
>     netHttpBinding
> - Using WebSocketHandler or WebSocketHost provided in
>     Microsoft.WebSockets.dll

You will need at least Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 and a full version of IIS 8.

This will be a case of the server side code receiving the change event from SQL, and then communicating this event via the WebSocket to the web client.

Comment: i have no server. both sql server and vs are running on my windows 7 laptop.

Comment: The "server" is an architectural concept, not a physical box plugged into a rack.