# Database change notifications to a windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

I am using `WebAPI` to push some data in to the database.

A windows service operating in the same server has to get notified when a data is inserted by the `WebAPI`

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877273/change-notification-with-sql-server-2008) SO question which suggests using `Service Broker` or `SqlDependency` but the question seems to be asked quite a while ago.

I googled out but could not find any simpler solutions. All I wanna do is `when a new data is inserted to Database, a function in the the windows service should fire`.

Do we have any alternatives or a much similar solution in `WebAPI - Windows Services` context ?

Comment: Can the Windows Service simply poll the data for changes at regular intervals?  Simply looking for records in a given state?

Comment: @David: Actually, it is going to be `time-critical`. So, `polling` does not seem to be a good alternative.

Comment: Ah, in that case it does seem that `SqlDependency` is likely the way to go.  Unfortunately I've never used it, so I can't advise on the specifics.

Comment: SqlDependency/QueryNotifications provides low-latency without continuous polling.  Under the covers, it does a blocking receive of notifications and periodically repeats after a timeout.

Comment: Do you have the source code of both programs ? In this case you can use [Memory Mapped File](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. I don't like it very much, but you can use CLR Integration.

You can use it to write a trigger: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131045.aspx

It can contact external resources setting the correct permissions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345101.aspx

Then you can call your service via socket, or make it a webservice. But you need c# programming skills.